# Finding radius of convergence.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

I was asked to prove that $f(x)$ is derivative in $x=1/2$ but I found that the radious of convergence is $0$, what did I do wrong?
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n(2n+1)}$$

I put x outside the summation and declared $t=x^2$ then the radius is equal to limsup of $a_n^{1/n}$ which is $0$.

Comment: I think $\limsup (2n(2n+1))^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: why? isn't that &infty$?

Comment: $\log \lim n^{1/n} =\lim \log n^{1/n} = \lim \frac{ \log n}{n} = 0$, so $\lim n^{1/n} = 1$.  Similarly $ \lim (2n+1)^{1/n} = 1$, $\lim 2^{1/n} = 1$.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand that well

Comment: I organized and posted as answer. Let me know where you are stuck then I'll add comment or edit to improve the post.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to find the radius of convergence and they are based on the root test and the ratio tests.

The ratio test:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if $|\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}| < 1$ and diverges if $|\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}| > 1$  (and is inconclusive if the ratio equals one.)

The root test.

The series converges if $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sqrt [n]{a_n} < 1$ diverges if that limit is greater than 1 and is inconclusive if it equals 1.

By the ratio test $\frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}} = {\frac {\frac {(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n(2n+1)}}{\frac {(-1)^nx^{2n+3}}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}}} = {-\frac {(2n+2)(2n+3)}{2n(2n+1)x^2}}$

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} |-\frac {(2n+2)(2n+3)}{2n(2n+1)x^2}| = \frac {1}{x^2}$ which is less than $1$ when $x< 1$

If $x = 1$ then our our series

$\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{2n(2n+1)}$ converges.

$|x| \le 1$

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(2n(2n+1)\right)^{1/n} $$. If this limit converges to some positive number, the radius of convergence is its reciprocal since its limsup is the limit value.

Consider $$\log (2n(2n+1))^{1/n} = \frac{\log(2n(2n+1))}{n} = \frac{\log 2 + \log n + \log (2n+1)}{n}$$

Since $\frac{\log 2}{n}, \frac{\log n}{n}, \frac{\log(2n+1)}{n} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log (2n(2n+1))^{1/n} = 0$. Thus we have 
$$ \log\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} (2n(2n+1))^{1/n}\right) = 0$$ which give $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(2n(2n+1)\right)^{1/n} =1 $$

This is the plot of function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$. This function first increases, but eventually starts to to decrease, and converges to $1$ at $\infty$.
[image]